# HAML and JQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

I am trying to use jquery datepickers embedded in haml in that way:

```
%body
    %canvas#neoviz
    %header
      %section#title
        %h1 DateTest
      %section#search
        %form{:action => "/", :method => "get"}
          %label Start:
          %input#start{:type => "text", :value => "#{@start}", :name => "start"}
          %label End:
          %input#end{:type => "text", :value => "#{@end}", :name => "end"}
      %input#loadnode{:type => "submit", :value => "Search", :class => "button"}
  %br{:style => "clear: both;"}
%section#content
  = yield

  %script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
    $(function(){
      $('#start').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yymmdd', onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#start').datepicker('option','minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear,   inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
      }
    });
    $('#end').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yymmdd', onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $('#end').datepicker('option','maxDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
  });
});
```

But the calendars doesn't appear and my Sinatra App return this error "Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal"

at this line:

```
$('#start').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yymmdd', onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
```

Comment: I guess you shouldn't indent the javascript?

Comment: where is the closing `script`tag ?

Comment: But is this the correct way to embed javascript in haml code?

Comment: Nope, You should use [:javascript](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter) filter insstead. Moreover your %section#content is seems to be outside  the body tag -- that's inproper.